# What is the right approach on implementing Post/Redirect/Get Pattern in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post-redirect-get

For MVC 5 projects I used to use `RedirectToAction`, however, with .NET Core 2 or later, it looks like there are different approaches using `CreatedAtRouteResult` or `CreatedAtRoute`, something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson(Parameter person)
{       
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Account.Add(person);
        _context.SaveChanges();    
        return new CreatedAtRouteResult("ActionName", null, null);    
    }    
    return View("Index");
}
```

What is the right approach? would it be also applicable for .NET Core 3 or higher?

Comment: is your intended server response a 302 redirect or a 201 created?

Comment: @monty, both might be good options, so I think is this point it doesn't really matters.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from doing a redirect in the shown example.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetPerson(int id) {
    //...
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson(Parameter person) { 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        _context.Account.Add(person);
        _context.SaveChanges();    
        return RedirectToAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.Id });    
    }    
    return View("Index");
}
```

It is all a matter of preference there

`CreatedAtRouteResult` or `CreatedAtRoute` are usually seen with Web API endpoints where the HTTP response code is required by the client.

With views one tends to see the Post/Redirect/Get approach

Comment: So, it would be okay to say that `CreatedAtRouteResult` is for Web API actions and `ReidrecToAction` for MVC actions?

Comment: No it would not be Ok to say that. It depends on the nature of how API is to be used.

Comment: @Jamo `RedirectToAction` pretty much forces the consumer to bounce over to the URL provided, whereas `CreatedAtRoute` is more of a signpost to say "the new resource is available over there".

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateAtRoute`  is a helper method which inherits from `ControllerBase` .  What `CreateAtRoute()` does  is  simply returning a new `CreatedAtRouteResult(routeName, routeValues, value)` . There is no dark magic at all ([source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/64157c95c1f10992e81e8590e31e90b0b8bd5eeb/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L2023))

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <see cref="CreatedAtRouteResult"/> object that produces a <see cref="StatusCodes.Status201Created"/> response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="routeName">The name of the route to use for generating the URL.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The content value to format in the entity body.</param>
    /// <returns>The created <see cref="CreatedAtRouteResult"/> for the response.</returns>
    [NonAction]
    public virtual CreatedAtRouteResult CreatedAtRoute(string routeName, [ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
        => CreatedAtRoute(routeName, routeValues: null, value: value);
```

The `CreateAtRoute` method is often used within an `ApiController` , and the third parameter will be used as the content of response  . Let's say an action method :

```
public class HomeController : Controller{

    public IActionResult Index(){
        return CreatedAtRoute("HelloDetails",new {Id=1} , new Student{
            Id = 1,
            StudentEmail = "test@microsoft.com"
        });
    }
}
```

Then it will return the values with 201 status code without redirecting.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "studentEmail": "test@microsoft.com"
}
```

While using `RedirectToAction`, it will redirect to another action and return the result of that action.